# Error Building Android APK - duplicate v4 widget

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

When I "Build an APK," I am getting a "duplicate entry" error.

It's fine when I just build and run it in the emulator, or on an actual device.  When I go to build an APK for upload, it fails.

There are a ton of similar questions on Stackoverflow, which mostly point out support-v4 as the culprit...and the error spells it out as well.  I've tried eliminating all of them to no avail.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/CompoundButtonCompatLollipop.class
```

And here is my app's Gradle.build.  I put it in a gist to make it more readable.

https://gist.github.com/crowell256aa/eb38857b76bee88c8d66782d8fcf83b8

Comment: Please post all of your `build.gradle` questions. It is a duplicate dependency error.

Comment: I think you mean put the copy-paste the gradle into the question -- which makes sense.  However, when I do that, it doesn't appear as a code block but as an unreadable mess.   The gist is readable, so I chose that as the lesser of two evils.  Any suggestions as to how to make the build.gradle copy paste behave?

Comment: Please use the code formatter to show the `build.gradle` in the question.